# IIS 7.5 using Classic ASP converts a boolean value to a string in the local language

Tags: iis, iis-7, asp-classic, localization

I have a **Classic ASP** application running on a workstation with a **Danish version of Windows 7** with **IIS 7.5**.

**The problem:** When the application writes a boolean as a string, it will write "True" or "False" on an English server. However, on my Danish installation, it will write out "Sand" and "Falsk".

**The desired solution:** What I need is to know which specific setting on my workstation/iis/configuration determines which language it writes out a boolean value to make sure it will always write out booleans in English.

**I have tried the following already:**

- Set the LCID to 2057 (en_GB) for the ASP configuration of IIS.
- Changed settings in Control Panel to English

  - Regional settings
  - Number and currency formatting
  - Language for non-Unicode programs
- Changed the culture settings for ASP.NET in IIS
- Restarted the workstation.

**The following are not possible resolutions, so please don't suggest those:**

- Changing any code in the application.
- Re-installing my workstation with an English version of Windows 7.
- Changing the language of my Windows 7 installation (not possible because I am not using Ultimate and do not wish to upgrade)

Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I'm unsure about what to do with this question. I got good suggestions, but not the answer. Am I supposed to most useful answer anyway?

Comment: "choose the" fell out of my sentence above.  Am I supposed to choose the most useful answer anyway?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that the old OLEAUT regional settings hack applies, but I think it's worth a try - see what you get.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/271587

SetVarConversionLocale should be set to 2, and the default regional settings set to US English.

If that doesn't work, and you can't change code in your application, run a virtual machine with a US English OS. You didn't specifically exclude that :)

Comment: Microsoft state that the problem is only for Windows 2000 and that it was corrected in SP2 for Windows 2000, so I don't think that particular problem snugg back into Windows 7. The virtual machine idea is actually not all bad :)

Comment: The binary that includes support for the registry setting was included in Windows 2000 SP2. (that's the "fix" they're talking about, they're not saying "this problem goes away") I assume support for the registry setting has been carried forwards; as I said, it's worth a try.

Comment: Ahh okay, that makes sense. Unfortunately adding those registry keys didn't make any difference. I tried all of them and tried setting them to both 1 and 2 without any different result. I ran an iisreset in between.

Answer (score 0):

When you change regional settings in the control panel, you are doing this for your user profile; but IIS worker process usually run in other user contexts, depending on the configuration of the application pool(s). You should try changing the regional settings for those account(s).

Comment: I checked which application pool the website is using. I changed that application pool to identify itself as my own user account. I also tried with Network Service and "ApplicationPoolIdentity". It didn't work.Thanks for the suggestion, though-

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: I have also posted this solution to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15760035/boolean-values-in-local-language/44321629#44321629

Hi,

I was "caught" too with this "issue".
Indeed, this is not an issue :

## THE PROBLEM (EXAMPLE)

I had the same problem when using a boolean data in a SQL Statement.
On my French server, my SQL statement was the following :

```
<%
'Set my boolean value
Dim myBoolean
myBoolean = True

'Set my SQL Statement
Dim MySQLStatement
MySQLStatement = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyBooleanField = " & myBoolean
'=> Here, as MySQLStatement is a STRING, the boolean data was "converted/rendered" as a localized string. So that leads to this output :
'=> SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyBooleanField = Vrai
'Obviously, that SQL Statement is incorrect, because the SQL Engine does NOT understand what is the "Vrai" word - It should be "True" instead.
%>
```

## THE EXPLANATIONS :

- It does not matter which regional settings are set on your Windows System : Nothing happens to the underlying data. A boolean data type **is STILL** a *BOOLEAN*, in English, or French, or German, Russian, Thai, ..or any language you want.
- The fact is that the data **is simply being RENDERED** as a localized *STRING* (like dates).

## THE SOLUTION

After a lot of reading over forums threads, the solution is not to change regional settings on the Windows system, nor changing Registry keys, nor changing Session.LCID, ...
The absolute and code-only **solution is to convert the Boolean value (True|False) to an Integer (0|1)**. Then, this Integer will be safely usable in a string, and will remain (0|1).

**Here is the safe way** to use/convert/render a Boolean value in a non-localized form : **Use an Integer value**.

```
<%
'Set my boolean value
Dim myBoolean
myBoolean = True

'Set my SQL Statement
Dim MySQLStatement
MySQLStatement = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyBooleanField = " & BoolToInt(myBoolean)
'=> Here, as MySQLStatement is a STRING, and as the boolean data was previously "converted/rendered" as an integer, we got this correct SQL Statement :
'=> SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyBooleanField = 1
'This SQL Statement is correct, as the SQL Engine DOES understand that 1 is a boolean.

'This Function Returns an INTEGER value based on a BOOLEAN value
Function BoolToInt(v)
    '@param     v        Boolean    The Input Boolean Value to be converted to an Integer
    '@return    i_OUT    Integer    The Output Integer Value (0|1)

    'Convert the input value to a Boolean
    Dim b_v : b_v = CBool(v)

    'Define the Output Integer value
    Dim i_OUT

    'If the Input Boolean value is a "True" boolean value (in any language)
    if (b_v) then
        i_OUT = CInt(1)
    'If the Input value is a "False" boolean value (in any language)
    else
        i_OUT = CInt(0)
    end if

    'Return
    BoolToInt = i_OUT

End Function 'BoolToInt
%>
```

I really hope it save your day !